# How do i flip vertices onto the other side of a mirrored object

Tags: mesh, vertices, mirror-modifier

I'm need the vertices on the other side so I can connect them to the bangs [image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

To [mirror](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/mirror.html) geometry:

1. Select the bangs in edit mode.
2. Place the 3D Cursor at the pivot, over which you want to mirror. If this is the World origin you can snap it with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *World Origin*. If it is the object origin snap it to the object's origin <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Active Object*.
3. Use the 3D Cursor as the pivot. <kbd>.</kbd> > *3D Cursor*
4. Mirror in edit mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>.